# Sort by string value and print into HTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

Hello I've followed many topics around here but not found my working solution.
I've made this script that import a JSON array inside my Javascript function and then print it into an HTML table. I need to sort the data of JSON by "name" . Can you please correct my code? Many thanks.

EDIT --- with the help of Mihai the code is correct and is working

```
    $(function() {

    $.getJSON('./scripts/items.json', function(data) {

    function compareStrings(a, b) {
      // Assuming you want case-insensitive comparison
      a = a.toLowerCase();
      b = b.toLowerCase();
      return a.localeCompare(b);
    }

    data.birra.sort(function(a, b) {
      return compareStrings(a.name, b.name);
    })

    //console.log(birra);)

       $.each(data.birra, function(i, f) {
              var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.name + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.description + "</td>" + "</tr>"

               $(tblRow).appendTo("#table-birra tbody");
         });

    });

});
```

The comparison part was not working and broke my code...

I'm going to post "birra" array as asked:

```
    {"birra":[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Corona",
    "description": "La Corona Extra, è una birra Pale lager messicana, prodotta dal birrificio Cerveceria Modelo e, limitatamente alla produzione destinata all'esportazione nel territorio statunitense, dalla Constellation Brands",
    "country": "Messico"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Birra Moretti",
    "description": "Birra Moretti è stata un'azienda specializzata nella produzione di birra. Nasce nel 1859 a Udine con il nome di Fabbrica di Birra e Ghiaccio. Fu fondata da Luigi Moretti, un imprenditore, la cui famiglia era dedita al commercio e all'ingrosso di bevande e generi alimentari, il marchio è stato acquisito dalla società olandese Heineken nel 1996.",
    "country": "Italia"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Beck's",
    "description": "Beck's (ufficialmente \"Brauerei Beck & Co KG\") è un birrificio tedesco",
    "country": "Germania"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Forst",
    "description": "Birra Forst (in tedesco Spezialbier-Brauerei Forst) è il maggiore produttore italiano indipendente[1] di birra. Detentore anche del marchio Menabrea.",
    "country": "Italia"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Tabucchi",
    "description": "Birra italiana prodotta artigianalmente, molto maltata",
    "country": "Italia"
  }
]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `name` property it's a *string*, you need to use [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) method.

```js
let data = { "birra" :[{ "id": 1, "name": "Corona", "description": "La Corona Extra, è una birra Pale lager messicana, prodotta dal birrificio Cerveceria Modelo e, limitatamente alla produzione destinata all'esportazione nel territorio statunitense, dalla Constellation Brands", "country": "Messico" }, { "id": 2, "name": "Birra Moretti", "description": "Birra Moretti è stata un'azienda specializzata nella produzione di birra. Nasce nel 1859 a Udine con il nome di Fabbrica di Birra e Ghiaccio. Fu fondata da Luigi Moretti, un imprenditore, la cui famiglia era dedita al commercio e all'ingrosso di bevande e generi alimentari, il marchio è stato acquisito dalla società olandese Heineken nel 1996.", "country": "Italia" }, { "id": 3, "name": "Beck's", "description": "Beck's (ufficialmente \"Brauerei Beck & Co KG\") è un birrificio tedesco", "country": "Germania" }, { "id": 4, "name": "Forst", "description": "Birra Forst (in tedesco Spezialbier-Brauerei Forst) è il maggiore produttore italiano indipendente[1] di birra. Detentore anche del marchio Menabrea.", "country": "Italia" }, { "id": 5, "name": "Tabucchi", "description": "Birra italiana prodotta artigianalmente, molto maltata", "country": "Italia" } ]}

function compareStrings(a, b) {
  // Assuming you want case-insensitive comparison
  a = a.toLowerCase();
  b = b.toLowerCase();
  return a.localeCompare(b);
}

data.birra.sort(function(a, b) {
  return compareStrings(a.name, b.name);
})

console.log(data.birra);
```

Comment: Many thanks Mihai but still not working ... only the "birra.sort" function is breaking my code and I dont know why...

Comment: @DariusPum, can you post the `birra` array ?

Comment: @DariusPum, have a look to updated answer. I don't know why is not working for you.

Comment: copy - pasted your code and not working... what does it mean "let birra = ... ... " ?

Comment: Just assign the array to a variable. Well, I think I found the mistake in your code. Just use `data.birra.sort(function(a, b) {
      return compareStrings(a.name, b.name);
    })` and don't forget to use `localeCompare` as i said.

Comment: BINGO ! NOW IS CORRECT ! MANY THANKS !

Comment: @DariusPum, you're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer in order to help other people.